# Sink with ParallelFlux cause OOM

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, project-reactor

I have a reactive sink and I want to process the messages in a parallel way with ParallelFlux, but it seems that it release the kafkalistener thread and it will consume messages till there is not enough memory (I checked it with jmap and the memory was filled with Message<> instances).

I have to add that if there was no consumer lag then the messages was processed well, but if there was a significant consumer lag, then it started to consume the memory.

```java
@StreamListener(MySink.INPUT)
public void handleMessage(final Flux<Message<byte[]>> input) {
    input
            .parallel()
            .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .map(this::parseMessage)
            .filter(this::messageNotEmpty)
            .doOnNext(this::processMessage)
            .doOnNext(this::adjustState)
            .sequential()
            .subscribe(this::acknowledgeMessage);
}
```

Please help, how can i write a sink with parallel processing which blocks the main thread (kafkalistener) when the thread pool is full?